# Card.IO libraries is so large,how to reduce them?

Tags: card.io

card.io team:
     Our team use card.io sdk to scan bank card number,but we got a problem that is the so libraries is so large,  almost 4.1M. when packaged a apk about 2M.
     Our app is just 2M,so could you please suply some methods to reduce the so files.

Answer (score 1):

Josh from card.io here. We've actually taken considerable pains to get the SDK to be as small as it is! The card.io SDK does a significant amount of non-trivial client-side work and the resources required to do that have already been shrunk as far as we feel currently possible without negatively impacting usability.